# How does one style a specific row on v-data-table? [Vuetify]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

All I'm trying to do is for the given row that contains an entry that is equal to `lowestEntry`, change the background color.

```
<v-col cols="8">
        <v-data-table
          :loading="loadEntryTable"
          loading-text="A procurar dados..."
          :headers="this.entryheaders"
          :items="this.stockentries"
          :items-per-page="10"
        >
        //Have tried using the v-slot.item to achieve it but no success
</v-data-table>
</v-col>
```

I want to change the `tr` background color do green. Sort of highlight it when `ìtem.id_entry == lowestEntry["id_entry"]`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you're using newer versions of vuetify, you have access to `item-class` as a property of the `v-data-table`. This will provide the `item` as the first argument to the callback function.

```html
<v-data-table
....
:item-class="itemRowBackground"
></v-data-table>
```

And then define the function which will return the class name:

```js
methods: {
  itemRowBackground: function (item) {
     return item.protein > 4.2 ? 'style-1' : 'style-2'
  }
}
```

Then just define the classes for `style-1` and `style-2`:

```css
.style-1 {
  background-color: rgb(215,215,44)
}
.style-2 {
  background-color: rgb(114,114,67)
}
```

Here's a code pen for this example that will work for you [codepen example](https://codepen.io/gswits/pen/YzqEJMZ)

**Edit** If `:item-class` is not available for your current version of Vuetify,  or you need more control over the row other than just binding a class, you'll have to use the `item` slot and bind the class/style/etc manually.

Target the `item` slot and bind the class to the row manually:

```html
<v-data-table>
    <template #item="{ item }">
      <tr :class="item.id_entry === lowestEntry['id_entry'] ? 'custom-bg' : ''">
        <!-- manually define all of your <td> elements now. -->
      </tr> 
    </template>
<v-data-table>
```

Alternatively, you can pass `:class="customRowClass(item, lowestEntry)"` and define the `customRowClass` method:

```js
methods: {
  customRowClass (item, lowestEntry) {
  return item.id_entry === lowestEntry['id_entry'] ? 'custom-bg' : ''
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It did work creating the method with the comparison and returning CSS class name.

Comment: I get `item is undefined` in the function

Comment: `Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

Comment: how did this answer get accepted, when the code does not work?

Comment: @AntonioNicolaasTeyken Admittedly, at the time of writing this was correct, but it is missing a key piece of the puzzle. Anyway, things have changed and now you have access to `item-class` which accepts a function that receives the item as it's first argument. I've updated the answer to reflect the 2 methods given your Vuetify versions.

Answer (score 12):

Based on totalhacks suggestion, the new vuetifys item-class:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    row_classes(item) {
        if (item.calories < 200) {
          return "orange";
        } 
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      singleSelect: false,
      selected: [],
      headers: [{text: 'Dessert', value: 'name'},{ text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },],
      desserts: [{name: 'Frozen Yogurt',calories: 159,},{name: 'Ice cream sandwich',calories: 237,},{name: 'Eclair',calories: 262,},{name: 'Cupcake',calories: 305,},],
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.4/dist/vuetify.min.css'>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.4/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :item-class= "row_classes"                  
    >
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually helps, also a cleaner and more straight forward hack could be to just return the color you wish to apply: example:
``
 row_classes(item) {
        if (item.calories < 200) {
          return "red";
        } 
    }
``
Or something else! without necessarily adding in some CSS

Answer (score 1):

You could use `v-bind:` on class and create a method to change the `tr` background color.

Please below working code snippet

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  //vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    getClass(calories) {
      //Here you can put your condition based on your logic...
      if (calories == 237) return 'orange';
      else if (calories == 305) return 'green';
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: JSON.parse('[{"text":"Dessert (100g serving)","align":"left","sortable":false,"value":"name"},{"text":"Calories","value":"calories"},{"text":"Fat (g)","value":"fat"},{"text":"Carbs (g)","value":"carbs"},{"text":"Protein (g)","value":"protein"},{"text":"Iron (%)","value":"iron"}]'),
      desserts: JSON.parse('[{"name":"Frozen Yogurt","calories":159,"fat":6,"carbs":24,"protein":4,"iron":"1%"},{"name":"Ice cream sandwich","calories":237,"fat":9,"carbs":37,"protein":4.3,"iron":"1%"},{"name":"Eclair","calories":262,"fat":16,"carbs":23,"protein":6,"iron":"7%"},{"name":"Cupcake","calories":305,"fat":3.7,"carbs":67,"protein":4.3,"iron":"8%"},{"name":"Gingerbread","calories":356,"fat":16,"carbs":49,"protein":3.9,"iron":"16%"},{"name":"Jelly bean","calories":375,"fat":0,"carbs":94,"protein":0,"iron":"0%"},{"name":"Lollipop","calories":392,"fat":0.2,"carbs":98,"protein":0,"iron":"2%"},{"name":"Honeycomb","calories":408,"fat":3.2,"carbs":87,"protein":6.5,"iron":"45%"},{"name":"Donut","calories":452,"fat":25,"carbs":51,"protein":4.9,"iron":"22%"},{"name":"KitKat","calories":518,"fat":26,"carbs":65,"protein":7,"iron":"6%"}]')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table items-per-page="10" :headers="headers" :items="desserts" >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <tr v-bind:class="getClass(props.item.calories)">
      <td v-for="key in Object.keys(props.item)" :key="key">{{props.item[key]}}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In vuetify v3 you can use the property [row-props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-row-props) to adjust the styling of a row, e.g.

```html
 <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="some_items" :sort-by="[{ key: 'id', order: 'desc' }]"   :row-props="colorRowItem" >
```

The javascript functions looks likes this (very much simplified)

```js
function colorRowItem(item) {
  if (item.item.some_property != undefined && item.item.some_property.includes("Freigegeben")) {
    return { class: 'some_text' };
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a built-in way to do this now via the `item-class` property of `v-data-table`. See [this](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/11254) github issue that describes the feature a bit better than the [current documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/).