# Vuetify3 - v-data-table - change background of row depending on a value

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I would like to add the class **style_1** to any row where **lowest == 1** in my v-data-table.

I have tried many of the suggestions on SO without success. What am I missing here?

template

```
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="results"
    :row-props="rowProps"
  >
  </v-data-table>
```

method

```
rowProps(item) {
  if (item.lowest == 1) {
    return { class: "style_1" };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `row-props` does or if it's actually implemented yet. The [description](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-row-props) in the API documentation is currently missing. I would only attempt to use documented methods of modifying row data.  In this case, I would choose to use the [item slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#item-slot). This way you can bind your conditional class directly in the template.

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
  <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
    <tr :class="[item.lowest === 1 ? 'style_1' : '']">
      <td v-for="columnData in item">{{ columnData }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

[Playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thanks. I saw the detail was missing from the docs but reading various posts others seem to have got it working. I was trying to avoid using tr slots but if that is the only way. Also tried :item-class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961043/how-does-one-style-a-specific-row-on-v-data-table-vuetify but no joy.